# Taylor-polynomial of $f(x)=\log(\cos(x))$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

> $f: (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \log(\cos x)$
>
> Count the Taylor-polynomial $T_{2}(f, 0)(x)$ of the second degree of
>   $f$ in $x_{0} = 0$

Alright because it was saying second degree, I knew we will need one derivation of $f$ at least (is that correct?).
(Is it allowed to use more derivations if the task says second degree by the way?)

$f^{0}(x) = \frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln(10)}$

$f^{1}(x) = -\frac{\sin x}{\cos x\cdot \ln(10)}$

Put that into the Taylor formula: $(T_{n,x_{0}}f)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}f^{k}(x_{0})(x-x_{0})^{k}$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\log(\cos x) = \frac{\frac{\ln(\cos(0))}{\ln(10)}}{0!}*0(x-0)^{0} + \frac{-\frac{\sin(1)}{\cos(1)\cdot \ln(10)}}{1!}*0(x-0)^{1} + ..$$

$$\log(\cos x)=0$$

No wonder if we do it at $x_{0} = 0$ that it will all result in $0$...

But I must have done something wrong, don't think it's as easy as I did above, or is it? :o

Because now I cannot really create a series with this solution.

Comment: $$\int\tan x\  dx=?$$

Comment: I'm not allowed to use / work with integrals :(

Comment: For second degree, you also need the second derivative. Do they really want $\log_{10}$, or is $\log$ here the name of the natural logarithm?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One of my question is clear then.
But I don't know if it's meant to base 10 or natural, not mentioned anywhere (on the example exam)..

Comment: In mathematics, the symbol "$\log{x}$" means "logarithm to a base and it should be perfectly obvious to you what the base is", while "$\ln{x}$" means "logarithm to base $e$". In a text that alternates $\log{x}$ and $\ln{x}$, $\log{x}$ often means $\log_{10}{x}$. In a text that involves calculus and doesn't mention "$\ln{x}$", "$\log{x}$" usually means "$\log_e{x}$". In a computer science text that doesn't mention "$\ln{x}$", "$\log{x}$" can easily mean "$\log_2{x}$". So in this case, make life easier for yourself by assuming base $e$ rather than base $10$.

Comment: Thank you Martin and also thank you lab (now I know why you asked the thing with integral, although I'm not allowed to use it).
But that's not my problem then, if I don't know what the base is. Is it really  too hard for the professor to write one additional cent as info? 
But it wasn't my task anyway, probably the affected students were informed, so..
But interesting, I didn't know that $ln$ actually means $log$ to basis $e$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the derivatives one get:

$$f'(x_0)=-\tan(x)$$ 
$$f''(x_0)=-\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$
(Use the chainrule with $u=\log(x), v=\cos(x)$)

Then you get:
$$T_{f,0,2}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^2 \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{n!}\cdot x^n$$
$$T_{f,0,2}(x)=0-\tan(0)(x-0)-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$
$$T_{f,0,2}(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$

Comment: Thank you!
Does that mean my first derivation is wrong?
Oh yeah it is in deed, thank you very much again! :)

Comment: You're welcome. No, not at all. I'm not sure, why you used $ln(10)$ rather where it is coming from but: $\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\tan(x)$, so parts are correct.

Comment: I have used it because I didn't know how to derivate log(x).
But I knew $log(x) = \frac{ln(x)}{ln(10)}$
Now I found my mistake I think. Derivated wrong because I have ignored the factor $\frac{1}{ln(10)}$ completely ^.^

Comment: Ah, I see. It's easier to use the chainrule for the first derivative. The second derivative you can get with the quotient rule ;)

Answer (score 3):

We may compute the whole Taylor series from the Weierstrass product:
$$ \cos(x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
and the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$, leading to:
$$ \log\cos(x) = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4^m x^{2m}}{m\pi^{2m}(2n+1)^{2m}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(4^m-1)\,\zeta(2m)}{m\,\pi^{2m}}\,x^{2m}.\tag{2}$$
Since $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$, in a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ \log\cos(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}+O(x^6).\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for sharing another way of doing it!
However I cannot understand it sadly because Weierstrauss theorem hard for me to understand :P

Comment: @cnmesr: then just make a leap of faith: $(1)$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$, and the convergence of the infinite product (together with its derivatives) is uniform over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.